# Simulataneously skiprows and set header on pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

I want to read a pandas dataframe by skipping the first 13 rows, and then set the next row (row 14) as the column names (header). I would like to know if there is an efficient one-line solution because my following code is relatively verbose.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Kwan_27112020.txt", delimiter="\t", names=column_names, skiprows=13) # The 14th row is the column name, hence skip 13 rows (0-indexed)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df
```

Example data

```
df = pd.read_csv("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Kwan_27112020.txt", delimiter="\t", names=column_names) # The 14th row is the column name, hence skip 13 rows (0-indexed)
df.iloc[0:13,0:3].to_dict()

{0: {0: 'qlucore',
  1: '29',
  2: '33297',
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan,
  10: 'Gene Symbol',
  11: '---',
  12: '---'},
 1: {0: 'gedata',
  1: 'samples',
  2: 'variables',
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan,
  10: 'strand',
  11: '---',
  12: '---'},
 2: {0: 'version 1.2',
  1: 'with',
  2: 'with',
  3: nan,
  4: nan,
  5: nan,
  6: nan,
  7: nan,
  8: nan,
  9: nan,
  10: 'start',
  11: '---',
  12: '---'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `skiprows` and `header` simultanuously, the header count will start after the skipped rows.

```
pd.read_csv("/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Kwan_27112020.txt", delimiter="\t", names=column_names, skiprows=13, header=0)
```

Example:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

s = """a
b
col1
1
"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), skiprows=2, header=0)
```

Result:

```
   col1
0     1
```

Comment: It gives "ParserError: Too many columns specified: expected 63 and found 58" error.

Comment: so you need to check your `column_names` variable: it obviously has a length of 63 whereas there are only 58 columns in your csv. BTW, I don't understand why you specify the column names **and** read them from the file. If you manually specify the column names, you can just skip one more row (14) and set `header=None`.